# ggplot Box plots side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like side by side box plots (total and ELISA) by media type. I saw in other chats that I need to melt the data. When I do this I get the following

> Error: stat_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y

My data:

```
media    total    ELISA  
surface     1.3     2.7
surface     5.2     6.5
surface     0.9     2.9
surface     0.7     2.1
porewater   376.8   651.0
porewater   288.7   308.0
porewater   32.3    63.3
porewater   69.7    184.0
porewater   116.0   11.4
porewater   31.6    51.5
porewater   38.6    97.5
porewater   63.2    152.0
porewater   118.0   254.0
porewater   1147.5  4174.0
porewater   626.6   798.0
porewater   39.2    81.8
porewater   3.3     7.5
porewater   70.3    231.5
porewater   1.7     3.2
sediment    567.0   1454.1
sediment    24.0    70.7
sediment    13.7    23.9
sediment    16.9    105.7
sediment    39.7    5.9
sediment    8.2     17.6
sediment    27.4    85.0
sediment    14.7    30.8
```

My code:

```
library(reshape2)
elisa.m <- melt(elisa, media.vars='media', measure.vars=c('total','ELISA'))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(elisa.m) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = media, y=value)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5)
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  Should I be naming it something other than value?

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping `aes()` should be within `ggplot()` for `stat_boxplot` to inherit it. Therefore,

```
  p <- ggplot(elisa.m, aes(x = media, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5)
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the side by side box plots. I want total to be next to ELISA with media on the x axis.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
myplot = ggplot(elisa.m, aes(x=media, y=measurement))+
          geom_boxplot()+
          stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width=0.5) +  
          facet_rep_wrap(~mode, repeat.tick.labels=TRUE)
```

However, for this to be working, you must reorganize your data so you have the following format:

```
media   measurement  mode
surface    1.3       total
  .                  total
  .                  total
surface    2.7       elisa
  .                  elisa
  .                  elisa
```

Hope it helps :) 
Ana